# Intellij setup scala and spark

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, google-analytics, apache-spark-sql

I have Intellij IDEA community edition. I need help with configure Apache Spark for IntellJ. I want to get data from GA by Scala..I use crealytics..

My build.sbt:

```
name := "scala-project-test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.1",
  "com.crealytics" % "spark-google-analytics_2.11" % "0.8.1"
)
```

and analytics.scala

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

object analytics {


  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
  val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.crealytics.google.analytics")
    .option("serviceAccountId", "xxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
    .option("keyFileLocation", "/Users/userABC/IdeaProjects/scala-project-test/xxxx.p12")
    .option("ids", "ga:xxxxxx")
    .option("startDate", "7daysAgo")
    .option("endDate", "yesterday")
    .option("dimensions", "date,browser,city")
    .option("queryIndividualDays", "true")
    .load()

  df.select("browser", "users").show()
}
```

When I RUN Object Analytics, there is Error:
not found: value sc

I think there is issue about Spark Configuration, because sc is a SparkContext, but I dont know where is it.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

short answer

```
  val conf = createSparkConf
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
```

.....

Generally I use a SparkContextFactory

```
object SparkContextFactory {

  val conf = createSparkConf
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  def createSparkSQLContext: SQLContext = {
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sQLContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    sQLContext
  }

  def stopSparkContext() = sc.stop()

  private def createSparkConf: SparkConf = {
    val conf = ConfigLoader.conf

    val masterPath = conf.getString("spark.master.path")

    new SparkConf()
      .setMaster(masterPath).setAppName("SparkContext")
      .set( "spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts" , "true")
  }
}
```

in a configuration file you need to set a master url this is what it looks like for local box

```
spark.master.path="local[*]"
```

also the

```
set( "spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts" , "true")
```

is just for local testing I use the factory like this

```
val sqlc = SparkContextFactory.createSparkSQLContext
```

Comment: Also if you don't want to give VM argument or into configuration file like spark.master.path="local[*]", while creating SparkConf you can specify your configuration as well.      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App Name").setMaster("local").